# save the state of swipe button

Tags: sharedpreferences, swipe, android-button

I have this challenge whereby i need to track the attendance of the users, So I decided to create swipe-button `com.ebanx:swipe-button` where by the user will slide to clock in/out. Well my challenge I can't save it's state. I'd like If a user closes or changes to another activity the change/state is saved. I used Shared Preferences to try to save it but no luck.

I tried to follow this **stacks** but I didn't find them helpful

[How to change state of swipe button from code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418922/how-to-change-state-of-swipe-button-from-code)

[Save Toggle Switch / Checkbox State with SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628737/save-toggle-switch-checkbox-state-with-sharedpreferences?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[how do i keep the toggle state active when switching between fragments](https://github.com/ebanx/swipe-button/issues/51)

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        swipeButton = findViewById(R.id.swipe_button);
        SharedPreferences tog_prefs = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean pref_1 = tog_prefs.getBoolean("pref_1", false);
        if (pref_1) {
            swipeButton.setActivated(true);
        } else {
            swipeButton.setActivated(false);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);

        swipeButton.setOnStateChangeListener(new OnStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChange(boolean active) {
                if(active){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("pref_1", true); // value to store
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(Attendance.this,
                            "Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("pref_1", false); // value to store
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(Attendance.this,
                            "Not active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```